# How to stop 3D model from reflecting light like plastic

Tags: unity, 3d

I was browsing SketchFab and found a 3D model I decided to try in Unity.

This is how the model looks in SketchFab's viewer:

[image]

When I put it in Unity, I used a Directional Light object:

[image]

As you can see, it looks like plastic. I have been playing with the light's intensity, but the model seems to always reflect light as if it were some sort of plastic (unlike SketchFab's viewer).

How can I make it look like the above image?

The model is https://sketchfab.com/models/1ee9b44352c840bda4202895948c30bb

Comment: This mainly has to do with the material/shader you're using. It looks like you have specular highlights, and it sounds like you want to get rid of them. Perhaps you want a "diffuse" or "toon" shader?

Answer (score 1):

Specular highlights are controlled by the *Shader* of the *Material* assigned to the *MeshRenderer* component of an object.

The standard shader in Unity 5 has a slider for "Metallic" and "Smoothness". When you turn up the smoothness, your object will have a less glossy look. You could also try experimenting with the other shaders Unity has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely an issue of shader configuration.

Without completely reiterating [the workflow in the Unity manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMetallicVsSpecular.html), you'll probably want to apply the new [Standard Shader](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-StandardShader.html) and then, using the [material charts](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialCharts.html), and adjust the material's parameters accordingly.